# What are the legitimate values for partition key in Azure Table?

Tags: azure-table-storage

I'm using Azure Table for store a TFIDF model and have a table where the partition keys are the terms. They may have some characters such as "`" or "'". When inserting entities with these character, I get a Bad Request error. What characters are not allowed as the partition key in Azure Table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Table Storage RowKey restricted Character Patterns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514707/azure-table-storage-rowkey-restricted-character-patterns)

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179338.aspx) as it answers your question.

---

**Characters Disallowed in Key Fields**

The following characters are not allowed in values for the PartitionKey and RowKey properties:

•The forward slash (/) character

•The backslash () character

•The number sign (#) character

•The question mark (?) character

•Control characters from U+0000 to U+001F, including:

◦The horizontal tab (\t) character

◦The linefeed (\n) character

◦The carriage return (\r) character

•Control characters from U+007F to U+009F

Comment: Thanks. The list does not contain character single quote (') but this one looks to be restricted because whenever I try to add a partition key containing a single quote Azure Table return a Bad Request. Is that correct?

Comment: The same for a dot . character.